# Get sound informations on SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, cakephp, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm a French student working on UX.
I'd like to develop a web app based on SoundCloud Stream with some conditions :
I wanna classify the sounds by their tags (categories) to create automatics playlists.

For the moment, I don't figure out, how to catch those informations through the SoundCloud API.
I'm used to work with cakephp.

Have you ever try something like this ?

Thx you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoundCloud provides an API which will give you all the information you need. Though I've never used it, there's a [PHP SDK](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) which might be useful to you.

From there, if you want to get the stream information (that is, the same tracks you get when, while logged in, you see when you go to soundcloud.com/stream), you'll need to do authentication first. Information about that is here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connect

After that, make a request to one of the /me/activities endpoints described here http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities and you'll get some information about the tracks. A track will contain `tag_list` which you can then parse into individual tags and create a playlist or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible using CakePHP or any other Framework or languages. It's the principle of an API REST such as the Soundclound API, which let you retrieve a lot of information just by making HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT etc.) on defined URLs.

The best you can do now is to read the Soundcloud API documentation, there are plenty examples in different langages on how to do these HTTP requests.

Look at this for example, it shows you how to create a set of sounds :

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#creating-sets